# Testing dependent models with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am relatively new to ruby and rspec and was wondering how to solve following case or what is a preferred way to deal with similar situations. For simplification, let's assume I have following models:

```
class Products
  has_one :image
  has_one :category

  def create_document
    {
      title: title,
      image: image.url unless image.nil?,
      category: category.name unless category.nil?,
    }
  end
end

class Images
  belongs_to :product
end

class Categories
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I want to test four cases:

```
describe Product do
  # create all four products
  fixtures :products, :images, :categories

  it 'returns title' do
    # create only product
  end

  it 'returns title and category' do
    # create category
  end

  it 'returns title, image and category' do
    # create image
  end

  it 'returns title and image' do
    # remove category
  end
end
```

My problem is that all fixtures are created before my tests will even start to be executed. This means I can either create 4 products (which I know how to solve) and test each one of them separatelly or create one product and create images and categories as I proceed with my tests (which is still a puzzle to me and I don't know how to solve that). What is the best way to deal with such a test?

Here is my spec_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'

require_relative '../config/environment.rb'

require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rack/utils'

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"

  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    Rails.cache.clear rescue nil
    Time.zone = 'UTC'
  end

  # define the factories
  require 'factory_girl'

  # configure fixture options
  config.fixture_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # Build the fixtures
  require_relative 'support/fixture_builder'
end
```

Here is my fixture_builder.rb

```
require 'fixture_builder'

FixtureBuilder.configure do |fbuilder|
  fbuilder.files_to_check += Dir["spec/factories/**/*.rb", "spec/support/fixture_builder.rb"]

  fbuilder.factory do
    load(Rails.root.join('db/seeds.rb'))

    product_one = fbuilder.name(:product_one, FactoryGirl.create(:product, title: 'product 1')).first
    fbuilder.name(:image_one, FactoryGirl.create(:image, product_id: product_one.id, url: 'product 1 image url'))
    fbuilder.name(:category_one, FactoryGirl.create(:category, product_id: product_one.id, name: 'product 1 category'))
  end
end
```

And my factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product, class: Product do
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image, class: Image do
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category, class: Category do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FactoryGirl works as a replacement for fixtures. Thus you don't use the fixtures method with FactoryGirl, rather it has its own DSL:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:product) # Saves a product to the database
FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:product) # Builds a product and makes it look look like it has been persisted
FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product) 
# etc
```

You can setup shortcuts by including `FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` in your specs:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ..
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  # ..
end
```

You then use the factories in your specs with rspecs `let` and `let!` methods.

```
describe "Let methods and factories" do

  let(:product) { create(:product) } # initialized when it is used
  let!(:foo) { create(:foo) } # initialized before any specs are run

  describe "let" do
    expect(product).to be_a Product
  end
end
```

The [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) gem is invaluable for cleaning up inbetween specs avoid any test ordering issues or false positives.

In your case you may want to just use the factory straight off for each test case.

```
describe Product do

  # It is a good practice to put examples in a describe block 
  # which tells which method we are testing
  describe "#create_document" do

    it 'returns title' do
      product = build_stubbed(:product, title: build_stubbed(:title))
      expect(product.create_document()[:title]).to be_a Title
    end

    it 'returns title and category' do
      product = build_stubbed(:product, category: build_stubbed(:category))
      expect(product.create_document()[:category]).to be_a Category
    end
    #.. 
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also setup factories which use other factories. http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: My problem is a little bit more complex than that, because I am using engines and read only models that inherit from some shared libs. This causes factory girl to fail on creating the factories since the models are read only. That was the main reason to use rspec fixtures in conjuction with `set_fixture_class :products => ProductsApi::Product`. Nevertheless I didn't specify it in my question and your answer pointed me to the correct direction.